# TestLink execution update is not working with nose framework when run in thread

Tags: python, nose, testlink

I am using noseframework for an automation run.We have integrated it with testlink for marking pass/fail etc.It works well.

When I use the threading option --processes=10 to run it in multiple threads the same update is not happening.

I want to execute things in thread as well as update the testplan simultaneously.I am also curious to know what is happening behind the 
scene in thread that is preventing it from working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Testlink and Automation testing myself but I believe I encountered the same problem.

Try running this instead:

```
nosetests --processes=10 --process-timeout=600
```

I think the reason it wasn't working for you is because you didn't set a timeout. Since you're running multiple processes in parallel, you need to tell nose when to timeout for each test so it doesn't just freeze up when the test lags or put in an infinite loop or whatnot.

> Note: The number of processes and the process time is arbitrary to
>   suite your tests and what you're testing. Try to set a high timeout
>   though, like this one is set to 10 minutes.